# Render Views Filter as a Select List?

Tags: views, 8

In Drupal 7 I could have a view with exposed filters that actually referenced content types as shown below:

[image]

The views filter settings looked like this (below), where I could select the drop down options from a list of content types, instead of having to supply arbitrary values to compare to...

[image]

I think this was part of entity reference in D7 where I would check-off "Render Views Filters As Select List"

How can I have a views filter in Drupal 8 that is a dropdown list populated with a field from a number of nodes?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Asking a question doesn't mean to merely use the title field. You need to provide more details, and if you are asking about code, you need to provide that as well.